# React Native Firebase DataSnapshot

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to implement firebase into my React Native app with the following code:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase'
var fireBaseconfig = {
apiKey: "MY KEY",
authDomain: "MY DOMAIN",
databaseURL: "MY URL",
storageBucket: "MY BUCKET",
};
var firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(fireBaseconfig);
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref;
var query = rootRef.ref("items");
 query.once("value")
   .then(function(snapshot) {
   snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
   var key = childSnapshot.key;
   var childData = childSnapshot.val();
  });
});
```

I am getting the error: "undefined is not a function (evaluating 'rootRef.ref("items")')

I have followed several tutorials including the official documentation and haven't been able find a solution to this. Am I using the right syntax for React native?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `firebase.database().ref`, `ref` is a function so should be `ref()`.

Since that returns a `Reference`, you have to call `child()` to get a child.

So:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase'
var fireBaseconfig = {
apiKey: "MY KEY",
authDomain: "MY DOMAIN",
databaseURL: "MY URL",
storageBucket: "MY BUCKET",
};
var firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(fireBaseconfig);
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref();
var ref = rootRef.child("items");
ref.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
   snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
     var key = childSnapshot.key;
     var childData = childSnapshot.val();
   });
});
```

I also renamed the `query` variable, because it's actually not a query but just another reference to a child location.

Comment: Now if I want to grab values from the snapshot (childData.id for example) would the syntax be ref.childData? I can't seem to grab childData by itself.